# Migration needed for Google App Invites to Firebase Invites?

Tags: android, google-app-invites, firebase-invites

Seems Google App Invites are now Firebase Invites.  I've been using the beta App Invites.  Is there a significant difference, and is there any migration needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the exact same code in this release so no need to do anything now. I'd recommend migrating to Firebase when you get a chance as Firebase will get the new features.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same.  Package names and all